# Why don't I have permission on my folder on the new hard drive?

Tags: partitioning, permissions, mount, hard-drive

I added a new hard drive as storage only, and wanting to save something to the folder where I mount( /hdd) the drive doesn't let me. For example, try saving an html file

```
Failed to save 'html': Unable to write file '/hdd/html' (Unknown (FileSystemError): Error: Unknown system error -74: Unknown system error -74, open '/hdd/html')
```

Try to use the code that modifies the permissions

`chown -R user /hdd`

and this came out:

`chown: cannot read directory '/hdd': Bad message`

`sudo fdisk -l`

```
Disk /dev/sda: 298,09 GiB, 320072933376 bytes, 625142448 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD3200AAJS-6
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: A4E0084C-7105-4787-B6D2-A1D70A1B6CDD

Device     Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1   2048 625141759 625139712 298,1G Linux filesystem
```

/etc/fstab:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sdb2 during installation
UUID=04e3700b-e01f-4bd2-b273-6ee85780cf2e /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sdb1 during installation
UUID=3782-4CC0  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
UUID=b0ea8d6d-49c9-4a0e-b496-5df4b2a16e52    /hdd    ext4    defaults    0    0
```

[image]

Comment: Please don't touch anything outside your home directory if you don't know really what you are doing. Once your HDD/SSD is formatted, you can mount it in user space just like a pendrive. `/dev/sda` is probably your main disk, not the second one  you added for extra storage.

Comment: The error is very clear. FileSystemError) From your question. the drive has no file system or a file system the OS does not support.

Comment: use the `disks` utility (super key > enter `disks` or the waffle menu at the bottom of the dock to find it) and identify which drive it is from there

Comment: Also, don't use `/dev/sda#` as the drive identifier in `/etc/fstab`.  Instead use the `UUID=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX` where you get that from running `sudo blkid`.  The `/dev/sda#` can change by simply leaving a USB drive in when rebooting a system.